# how to pass field value to track variables in lwc and retrive the track variable in a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-wire-getlistui

Hello I want to pass the IsConverted value into a variable and retrieve it in a function

```
import { LightningElement,track,api,wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = ['Lead.CreatedDate', 'Lead.IsConverted','Lead.ConvertedDate'];

export default class LeadModularTimer extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track isConvert ;
    @track lead ;
      @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', FIELDS })
      wiredRecord({data }) {
         if (data) {
              this.lead = data;
              this.isConvert = this.lead.fields.IsConverted.value;
          }
        }

      connectedCallback(){
          var parentThis = this;
       console.log(parentThis.isConvert);// this is returing undefined 

      }
```

Comment: There's something I don't understand with your code. The isConvert variable is set via your wire method. The method is not called yet when your component initialized. The connectedCallback method is called at init so your isConvert is undefined. What do you want to do with this variable exactly?

Comment: thanks for the response @MartinLezer, I want to pass the IsConverted value into the isConvert variable thats it

Comment: Then you don't need the connectedCallback method. Your code is already supposed to work without it.